# Navbar submenu is not aligning with the menu item

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have tried to align my submenu with the navbar but it is not working, I think I must have done something wrong with the css, but can't figure it out.
CodePEN: https://codepen.io/wowasdi/pen/xxKzdQq

I have tried to change the navbar css settings with display: block, however it is not working.

[Image to nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpBLG.png)

CSS:

```
.container{
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.body-container{
  display: flex;
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-top:10%;
}
html{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    -ms-overflow-style:scrollbar
}
body{
    background:#ffffff;
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: "Raleway", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    min-height:400px;
    text-align:center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size:15px;
}
body #body{
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}
img{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto
}
/* Header **/
header{
  background:#000000;
  color:#ffffff;
  padding-top:30px;
  min-height:70px;
}

header #headerText{
  float:left;
  font-size: 30px;
}

header a{
  color:#ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size:16px;
}

header li{
  float:left;
  display:block;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

header ul li ul {
  background:#000000;
    visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  display: block;
  width: 8%;
}
header ul li:hover > ul,
header ul li:focus-within > ul,
header ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

header ul li ul li {
    clear: both;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

header nav{
  float: right;
}

header .highlight, header .current a{
  color:#e8491d;
  font-weight:bold;
}

header a:hover{
  color: #0FA0CE;
}

.burger div{
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  margin: 5px;
  display: none;
}


@media screen and (max-width:1255px){
  header li{
    display:inline;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  header ul li ul {
    background:#000000;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    min-width: 3rem;
    max-width: 7rem;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    display: none;
  }
  header ul li:hover > ul,
  header ul li:focus-within > ul,
  header ul li ul:hover {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
  }

  header ul li ul li {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;

  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1030px){
  body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav-menu{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color:#000000;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 30%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  .burger {
    margin-top: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .burger div{
    display: block;
  }
  header #headerText{
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:450px){
  body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .burger {
    margin-top: 16px;
  }
  .burger div{
    display: block;
  }
  header #headerText{
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .burger{
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .burger div{
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin: 5px;
  }
}
.nav-active{
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

Html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
    <div id="headerText">
            <div id="header"></div>
  </div>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-menu">
                 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="about.html">Page 1</a>
                 <ul class="dropdown">
                   <li><a href="#">SubPage 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">SubPage 2</a></li>
                 </ul>
                </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Contract</a></li>
          </li>
      <div class="burger">
          <div class="line1"></div>
          <div class="line2"></div>
          <div class="line3"></div>
      </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

          <div class="body-container">
            <div id="body"></div>
          </div>

  <script src="./js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some mistakes related to `position` and `overflow`.

I have changed your demo please check below link.

https://codepen.io/viralpatel508/pen/pozKdxe

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The position: absolute is getting carried down from the "header ul li ul". Once you remove that or change it to relative they should line up.